# is there any way to reuse a chain of pipe transformations in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, stream

For example if I have

```
readableStream.pipe(ws1).pipe(ws2).pipe(ws3)
```

How can I envelope that transformation chain in a single function and then reuse it in another transformation chain?

I want to do some like this:

```
var transformationChain1 = readableStream.pipe(ws1).pipe(ws2).pipe(ws3)
readableStream2.pipe(transformationChain1).pipe(endWs)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could probably use

```
var combine = require('stream-combiner2')
var ws = combine(ws1, ws2, ws3);
readableStream2.pipe(ws).pipe(endWs);
```

Comment: Yes Jerome, is that. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding (and my Node.js is rusty so it's entirely possible), but why not do exactly what you said and wrap it in a function?

```
function transformationChain(rs) {
  return rs.pipe(ws1).pipe(ws2).pipe(ws3);
}

var transformationChain1 = transformationChain(readableStream);
readableStream2.pipe(transformationChain1).pipe(endWs);
```

Comment: My point is that the parameter of transformationChain must be the result of readableStream2.pipe(), not a new readableStream. It is a little confusing for me too. I am trying to use stream combiner https://www.npmjs.org/package/stream-combiner, but maybe I am misunderstanding and complexing the things. :)

Comment: I guess this is over my head, then. Perhaps it would help you to draw a diagram, or write a more concrete example?