# reusing stream pipeline/sub-pipeline in Node.js/Gulp

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, gulp

starting out with streams/gulp/vinyl and trying to clean up/DRY my gulpfile using [stream-combiner2](https://github.com/substack/stream-combiner2). so far it is working well except now i need to run a sub-pipeline inside another pipeline (simplified psuedocode-ish):

```js
var logger = require("gulp-logger"),
HTMLPrettify = require("gulp-html-prettify"),
combiner = require("stream-combiner2"),
through = require("through2"),
tap = require("gulp-tap"),
_ = require("lodash");


preprocessPipeline = function() {
  return combiner.obj(getFrontMatter(), processTemplates());
};


gulp.task("build", ["clean"], function() {
    return gulp.src("in/**/*.html")
        .pipe(preprocessPipeline())
        .pipe(tap(function(file) {
            var data, dataSources;
            dataSources = getDataSources(file);
            data = {};

            /* PAUSE MAIN PIPELINE HERE */
            /* RUN THIS SUB PIPELINE BELOW */
            gulp.src(dataSources)
                .pipe(preprocessPipeline())
                .pipe(tap(function(file) {
                    _.merge(data, file.data);
                }));

            file.data = data;
            /* RESUME MAIN PIPELINE */
        }))
        .pipe(HTMLPrettify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("out"));
});
```

as you can see, inside the main "build" pipeline i am trying to do the following for each vinyl file object that comes down the main pipeline:

- pause execution of main "build" pipeline
- get the data source paths for the current vinyl file via the synchronous `getDataSources()` function
- use another sub pipeline to process those data source paths, reusing the `preProccessPipeline` and eventually merging their data
- finally the merged data from the data sources is added the the vinyl file in the main pipeline and execution continues in the main pipeline

`gulp.src()` looks like the perfect way to load these data source files into the sub-pipeline but the main pipeline seems to be completing before the sub-pipeline starts.

also, i am starting to realize that perhaps my pipelines are looking like synchronous function flow and most likely i am missing a key piece of the stream/node.js puzzle.

related docs that have helped me reuse pipelines but not with sub-pipelines:

- https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/sharing-streams-with-stream-factories.md
- https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/make-stream-from-buffer.md

related issues:

- [is there any way to reuse a chain of pipe transformations in NodeJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26220485/is-there-any-way-to-reuse-a-chain-of-pipe-transformations-in-nodejs)

thanks.

Comment: Can I ask what the purpose of this gulp file is? Do you just want to build your source files? If so, what does that build step look like? It seems like you're combining data from multiple files, I'm not sure if that's entirely necessary. I've been using gulp / grunt files a fair amount and never seen something like this before; can't really help unless I know the main goal

Comment: @KeenanLidral-Porter the gulp file is for building a static website. as i tried to show the main template files need to be preprocessed for front matter, then have their templates evaluated, producing output. the template files also depend on data files (e.g. includes) for context. these data files also need to be preprocessed for front matter and have templates evaluated, and it is not possible to know the data file(s) associated with a template file until the template is processed. thus, i am trying to reuse the preprocess subpipeline for both file types, but w/in the same main pipeline. thx

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're using gulp as a templating engine of sorts—totally doable.

Gulp lets you specify which tasks are dependent on others, so you could break out that sub-pipeline into a new task, say `"buildDataFiles"`, then have your build task depend on that one i.e.

```
gulp.task("build", ["buildDataFiles", "clean"], function(){
```

But the problem with this approach is, as you said, "it is not possible to know the data file(s) associated with a template file until the template is processed." If you're sure there's no way around that, it gets trickier. What if instead you broke out the main pipe into a `"processTemplate"` task, the `"build"` task then only handles the sub-pipeline but depends on `"processTemplate"` ? It could look something like this:

```
gulp.task("processTemplate", ["clean"], function() {
  gulp.src("in/**/*.html")
    .pipe(preprocessPipeline())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("build/temp"));
}

gulp.task("build", ["processTemplate"], function() {
  gulp.src("build/temp/*.html")
    .pipe(tap(function(file) {
      var data, dataSources;
      dataSources = getDataSources(file);
      data = {};

      gulp.src(dataSources)
        .pipe(preprocessPipeline())
        .pipe(tap(function(file) {
          _.merge(data, file.data);
        }));

      file.data = data;

    }))
  .pipe(HTMLPrettify())
  .pipe(gulp.dest("out"));
}
```

It looks really similar, but the problem your running into requires that the templates be processed first, then the data files. I would try checking out [gulp-consolidate](https://github.com/timrwood/gulp-consolidate), it may help you out.

Answer (score 1):

I find [stream-combiner](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-combiner) much more straight to the point

```
function coffeePipe() {
  return Combine(
    coffeescript(),
    coffeelint.reporter('fail')
  )
}
//usage:
gulp.src().pipe(coffeePipe());
```