# Node.js. How to pass a several streams (array or chain) into pipe?

Tags: node.js, node.js-stream

I have a function returning a several streams:

```
// function 
var s1 = through.obj({highWaterMark: 2}, function(data, enc, next) {
    console.log( "A: "+data );
    next(null, "A");
});

var s2 = through.obj({highWaterMark: 2}, function(data, enc, next) {
    console.log( "B: "+data );
    next(null, "B");
});

return [s1, s2]; 
// or chain:
// s1.pipe(s2);
// return s1;
```

I want to pass the result of function into pipe:

```
gulp.src(...).pipe(...).pipe( getStreams() ).pipe(gulp.dest...);
```

Is there way to do such?

Or maybe I can do it somethig like the next?

```
var s1 = getStreams();
gulp.src(...).pipe(...).pipe( s1 )
s1.getLastStreamOfChain().pipe(gulp.dest...);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a few ways to do this.
1)

```
s1.pipe(s2);
s1.lastStreamOfChain = s2;

stream.pipe(s1).lastStreamOfChain.pipe(s3); // Of course it is not good
```

2)
Use the stream-combiner2.

```
combine.obj(s1, s2);
```

[is there any way to reuse a chain of pipe transformations in NodeJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26220485/is-there-any-way-to-reuse-a-chain-of-pipe-transformations-in-nodejs)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`merge-stream`](https://github.com/grncdr/merge-stream) module:

```
const mergeStream = require('merge-stream');
gulp.src(...).pipe(...).pipe(mergeStream(s1, s2)).pipe(gulp.dest...);
```

Comment: merge-stream doesn't work. I think it is only for not obj stream.

Comment: You can use merge-stream for obj streams as well. I think I misunderstood your problem though. You'd like to pipe like this: `src.pipe(getStreams()).pipe(dest)`, where getStreams() would return a chain of streams right?

Comment: getStreams() must return a few streams. All the same it will be chain or merged another way. See my example: http://plnkr.co/edit/ufSKTaUh7fWkzuJhFrQU?p=catalogue

Comment: merge-stream merge only stream's datas.